# extracting SE from a list of results

Tags: r

if you run this code you will see 5 regressions

```
library(quantreg)
data(engel)
xx <- income - mean(income)
fit2 = summary(rq(foodexp~income,tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)))
fit2
```

each has a lower bd and upper bd

I would like to extract the coef and lower and upper bound for the INTERCEPT and put it in a data table

right now to access the coef, and upper and lower intercepts for each regression I use [[]] , then grab the 1st row , then rbind:

```
rbind(coef(summary(  fit2  )[[1]])[1,] ,
coef(summary(  fit2  )[[2]])[1,],
coef(summary(  fit2  )[[3]])[1,],
coef(summary(  fit2  )[[4]])[1,],
coef(summary(  fit2  )[[5]])[1,])
```

But there has to be an easier way that is dynamic...What is there are 20 regressions instead of 5?   Thank you.

Comment: If I run that code I get an error - `engel$xx <- engel$income - mean(engel$income)` I think you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(quantreg)
data(engel)
fit2 = rq(foodexp~income, tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95), data = engel )

do.call('rbind', lapply(summary(fit2), function(x) coef(x)[1,]))
#      coefficients lower bd  upper bd
# [1,]    124.88004 98.30212 130.51695
# [2,]     95.48354 73.78608 120.09847
# [3,]     81.48225 53.25915 114.01156
# [4,]     62.39659 32.74488 107.31362
# [5,]     64.10396 46.26495  83.57896
```

Based on @thelatemail suggestion - using `sapply`

coefficients of Intercept

```
sapply( summary(fit2), function(x) x[['coefficients']][1,] )
#                   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
# coefficients 124.88004  95.48354  81.48225  62.39659 64.10396
# lower bd      98.30212  73.78608  53.25915  32.74488 46.26495
# upper bd     130.51695 120.09847 114.01156 107.31362 83.57896
```

coefficients of income

```
sapply( summary(fit2), function(x) x[['coefficients']][2,] )
#                   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# coefficients 0.3433611 0.4741032 0.5601806 0.6440141 0.7090685
# lower bd     0.3433270 0.4203298 0.4870223 0.5801552 0.6739000
# upper bd     0.3897500 0.4943288 0.6019890 0.6904127 0.7344405
```

Comment: @thelatemail I believe that the **broom** package has a `tidy` method that does this for `rq` models.

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept it. Thanks